# MultiValueMap casuing issue application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

I need to do a request to a server. I'm using Spring Boot 2.5 and restTemplate.
The endpoint consumes the MediaType application/x-www-form-urlencoded, but when request is send returns a error "endpoint only accepts application/x-www-form-urlencoded for POST requests". In debug I saw that content type send in restTemplate is: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8.

Code:

```
 public void getToken(){
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        
        ResponseEntity<TokenResponseDTO> responses = restTemplate
                .postForEntity(url, new HttpEntity<>(getForm(), getHeaders()), TokenResponseDTO.class);

        log.info(responses.toString());
    }

    @NotNull
    private MultiValueMap<String, String> getForm() {
        LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("param1", "1");
        map.add("param2", "2");
        map.add("param3", "3");
        return map;
    }

    public HttpHeaders getHeaders(){
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        headers.add("header1", "aaa");
        return headers;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. IN my case worked

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    
    //Forma data
    MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    map.add("resourceServer", "ml-b2b-internet");
    map.add("client_id", clientId);
    map.add("client_secret", clientSecret);
    map.add("scope", "APP-284-PRF-77");


    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

    ResponseEntity<TokenDto> response = restTemplate.postForEntity( tokenUrl, request , TokenDto.class );

    var resp = response.getBody();
```

Comment: It's not working for me, the same error.
In content type of request have this: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8

Comment: Have you tested the request with an external tool such as Postman or curl to make sure that the server works as you expect? Check also the return type in my example is a json response

Comment: Yes, the server response is a json and the server is working expect

Comment: try to map a generic Json object as return type 
ResponseEntity<ObjectNode> response = restTemplate.postForEntity( tokenUrl, request , ObjectNode.class );     If it down't work try to map a Generic String    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity( tokenUrl, request , String.class );